# Regular expression for ignoring the First set of letters or a word in a object name in python

Tags: python, regex, squish, object-identity

" :NYSE Connect_LCAppendedButton " is the object name in our application which keeps changing. The set of words before _LCAppendedButton  keeps changing according to our application needs. How do we ignore those set of word "NYSE Connect" or replace with regular expression? Pleae help

Comment: `:\S+ \S+_LCAppendedButton` regex will match what you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
import re

def replace_button_prefix(btn_pfix):
    return re.sub(r'^.*(_LCAppendedButton)$', r'\1', btn_pfix)
```

#### Demonstration

```
replace_button_prefix(" :NYSE Connect_LCAppendedButton")

'_LCAppendedButton'
```